# VBA to send Excel Worksheet as PDF and Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I found some coding to send my worksheet in an email as a pdf (I forgot what website it was on, so thank you if you created it on here!). I have been asked if I can include an excel version of the file in the email, along with the current pdf file (some people need it to copy and paste into other reports). Below is my current VBA. I cannot figure out how to also attach the current Worksheet as an excel file into the email as an attachment.

Thanks for any help!

```
Sub AttachActiveSheetPDF()
  Dim IsCreated As Boolean
  Dim i As Long
  Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String
  Dim OutlApp As Object

  ' Not sure for what the Title is
  Title = Range("A1")

  ' Define PDF filename
  PdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  i = InStrRev(PdfFile, ".")
  If i > 1 Then PdfFile = Left(PdfFile, i - 1)
  PdfFile = Format(Now(), "MM-dd-yyyy") & " File Name" & ".pdf"

  ' Export activesheet as PDF
  With ActiveSheet
    .PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
  End With

  ' Use already open Outlook if possible
  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
  End If
  OutlApp.Visible = True
  On Error GoTo 0

  ' Prepare e-mail with PDF attachment
  With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

' Prepare e-mail
.Subject = "Email Name " & Format(Now(), "MM-dd-yyyy")
.To = "xxx" ' <-- Put email of the recipient here
.CC = "" ' <-- Put email of 'copy to' recipient here
.Body = "All," & vbLf & vbLf _
      & "xxx." & vbLf & vbLf _
      & "Regards," & vbLf _
      & Application.UserName & vbLf & vbLf
.Attachments.Add PdfFile

' Try to send
On Error Resume Next
.Send
Application.Visible = True
If Err Then
  MsgBox "E-mail was not sent", vbExclamation
Else
  MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", vbInformation
End If
On Error GoTo 0

  End With

  ' Delete PDF file
  Kill PdfFile

  ' Release the memory of object variable
  Set OutlApp = Nothing



End Sub
```

Comment: "I cannot figure out..." What steps have you taken and what have you discovered?

Comment: I have tried using the below, after the "export activesheet as PDF block"   
  With ActiveSheet
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Filename:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
  End With

Comment: I could get it to work using .Attachments.Add (file path) - putting this immediately after the .Attachments.Add PdfFile under prepare e-mail". This won't work because the file will be sent out to 3 different people and I'm not sure they will have it on their desktop. If I tell them all to put it on their desktop is there a way to make it work?

Comment: I tried this after the "Prepare email" section. ThisWorkbook.Save
source_file = ThisWorkbook.FullName
myMail.Attachments.Add source_file

Comment: It also looks like you can't use a wildcard character in VBA for file path, is that correct? I was trying to create the attachment by adding .Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\FileName.xlsm"). It seems like this would be the easiest way, if there is in fact a way to have it automatically insert the username of the person whose computer the file is on.

Comment: I added in a command to save the file, so it will attach an Excel file with all of the updates. Additionally, I got it to attach to the email with  .Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\FileName.xlsm"). Is there any way to get it to change the name to where it will input the Date in the file name. The PDF file does that.

Comment: Also, is there a way to export/attach only the active worksheet instead of the entire Workbook?

Answer (score 3):

You could save a worksheet as pdf file and email it as an attachment using the below code:

```
Sub Saveaspdfandsend()
Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range

Set xSht = ActiveSheet
Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
   xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
Else
   MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
   Exit Sub
End If
xFolder = xFolder + "\" + xSht.Name + ".pdf"

'Check if file already exist
If Len(Dir(xFolder)) > 0 Then
    xYesorNo = MsgBox(xFolder & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", _
                      vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
    On Error Resume Next
    If xYesorNo = vbYes Then
        Kill xFolder
    Else
        MsgBox "if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
    'Save as PDF file
    xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xFolder, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

    'Create Outlook email
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    With xEmailObj
        .Display
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = xSht.Name + ".pdf"
        .Attachments.Add xFolder
        If DisplayEmail = False Then
            '.Send
        End If
    End With
Else
  MsgBox "The active worksheet cannot be blank"
  Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[How To Save A Worksheet As PDF File And Email It As An Attachment Through Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4412-excel-save-as-pdf-and-email.html)

If you want to attach the current worksheet as an excel file into the email as an attachment, please refer to the below code:

```
Option Explicit 

Sub EmailandSaveCellValue() 

     'Variable declaration
    Dim oApp As Object, _ 
    oMail As Object, _ 
    WB As Workbook, _ 
    FileName As String, MailSub As String, MailTxt As String 

     '*************************************************  ********
     'Set email details; Comment out if not required
    Const MailTo = "some1@someone.com" 
    Const MailCC = "some2@someone.com" 
    Const MailBCC = "some3@someone.com" 
    MailSub = "Please review " & Range("Subject") 
    MailTxt = "I have attached " & Range("Subject") 
     '*************************************************  ********

     'Turns off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

     'Makes a copy of the active sheet and save it to
     'a temporary file
    ActiveSheet.Copy 
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook 
    FileName = Range("Subject") & " Text.xls" 
    On Error Resume Next 
    Kill "C:\" & FileName 
    On Error Goto 0 
    WB.SaveAs FileName:="C:\" & FileName 

     'Creates and shows the outlook mail item
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0) 
    With oMail 
        .To = MailTo 
        .Cc = MailCC 
        .Bcc = MailBCC 
        .Subject = MailSub 
        .Body = MailTxt 
        .Attachments.Add WB.FullName 
        .Display 
    End With 

     'Deletes the temporary file
    WB.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly 
    Kill WB.FullName 
    WB.Close SaveChanges:=False 

     'Restores screen updating and release Outlook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
    Set oMail = Nothing 
    Set oApp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[Send Excel sheet as email attachment using worksheet data.](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=350)