# Send excels all month to customers, by mail

Tags: excel

I would like my computer to send Excel files to my clients automatically, all the first of the month. I have a file on my computer that contains Excel files (one for each client)( let’s say that the name of each file is client1, client2...) and in each excel, there is a table of gain and loss. It takes me a lot of time to send them one by one, and I would like to find a way to send his Excel automatically, without my intervention, every month.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since you are new to SO, you may want to take the [tour] and also see [ask].

Comment: I already knew but thank you :)

Comment: You may want to [edit] your question accordingly then. Otherwise it's likely to be closed.

Comment: What change do I need to make to get it right?

Comment: It would be best to show what you've tried so far, and explain how it's not working.

Comment: don’t know how at all, I don’t try because I’m not an expert in the field

Comment: Surely you can research similar questions here on SO?

Comment: I was looking for similar questions, but they do not answer my question, I would really need help for this specific question

Comment: Yes, but they give you an *idea* of where to start. Unfortunately the question as it stands is too broad for this forum.

Comment: You are  suggesting me to  rephrase it?
I tried answers to other similar questions, without success...

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/q/53836405/4961700

Comment: It's not help, and it's a lot of code, and I don't know how to code...